# How do you say in a correct way using some technique?

Tags: article-writing

Sorry, I know it's not really related to Math itself, but I still need a native English Mathematician to help me through that and don't know where else to ask... So please don't close it because it might be subjective - I really just want to know how to say it in a correct way;
It would be embarassing to have 5 words in English and they are still wrong;

So I got a title for my thesis and I want to add just the English title in case I later give it to employers or universities abroad;
So the title is Primality Testint using Jacobi Sums;

However I don't know how to write the "using" part; I want to say that I do Primality Tests with the help of Jacobi Sums;
How do I say it in a correct and of course elegant way?

Primality Testing using Jacobi Sums

Primality Testing due to Jacobi Sums

Primality Testing based on Jacobi Sums

Can someone help? Many thanks!! :)

Comment: Well, the "due to" option feels completely wrong, don't use that one. The other two seem much better to me.

Comment: Okay, I already wrote that; Seemed elegant to me - thanks for telling me, that helped a lot, actually :)

Comment: 'Primality Testing with Jacobi Sums' or 'Testing for Primality with Jacobi Sums' also work for me.

Comment: But option 1 and 3 of my suggestions as well?

Comment: Both of options 1 and 3 look fine.

Comment: Okay thank you all; You helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacobi Sums as a Method for Primality Testing;

Jacobi-Sum Methods in Primality Testing;

Jacobi Sums for Primality Testing;

Primality Testing using Jacobi Sums;